# When considering an equation on flat torus, can we treat it as an equation on a square with opposite sites topologically identified?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I need to use some theorems (**which is originally for $2$-dim bounded domain in Euclidean space**) on torus, what should I do to the equation? Can I just simply treat it as an equation on a square with opposite sites topologically identified?

For example, if on torus
$$
\Delta u = f(x,u).
$$
Can we just solve
$$
\Delta u = f(x,u),
$$
on square with $$f(x,\frac{1}{2})=f(x,-\frac{1}{2})$$ for $x \in [-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}]$
and $$f(-\frac{1}{2},y)=f(\frac{1}{2},y)$$ for $y \in [-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: Is your square [-1/2, 1/2]^2 ?  Then identifying opposite sides of the square **is** (one example of) a flat torus.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I'm confused about a definition of distance function on torus, I add more details in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467984/using-a-theorem-which-is-originally-set-on-2-dim-bounded-domain-in-euclead-spac

Comment: The distance function on the square torus ℝ^2 / ℤ^2 can be defined as d((a,b), (c,d))  =  √((min{|c-a|, 1-|c-a|})^2 + (min{|d-b|, 1-|d-b|})^2). This is the length of the shortest straight line segment on the torus that connects the two points.